# smbclient getting NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE connecting to Windows box

Tags: windows, samba

I'm running smbclient on Ubuntu, trying to connect to a Windows box, and I'm getting "session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE".

I've verifed that I can ping the box and telnet to ports 139/445, so I'm pretty sure that it's not a firewall issue.  And my client says that they can connect to this Windows box from another Windows box with the userid/password combination without issue.  Also, this box can connect via smbclient to other Windows boxes that this client has.

Any other ideas for why this isn't working?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Have you checked your smb.conf?

Make sure your workgroup and security settings are properly set.  If you are working with a a computer as part of a domain, authentication requests are first passed through your domain controller, so make sure you have something similiar to:

```
security = domain
workgroup = WORKGROUP
```

You can also use the `-W` option to specify the workgroup, and add `DOMAIN/` before your username to specify the domain:

```
$smbclient -L myhost -U DOMAIN/user -W workgroup
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Turns out adding the domain did the trick.  Apparently some versions of Windows require the domain and others don't?  But, thanks!

Comment: note that the 'security = domain' bit is unnecessary here. Apart from specifying the workgroup in smb.conf, you can also specify it on the command line to smbclient.

Comment: Yes, the -W option to smbclient is what I used to get it working.

Comment: DOMAIN/username should also work.

Comment: You may also use smbclient with the -W argument.

Comment: dont forget 
smbpasswd -a user

Comment: Is `domain` word used literally in `security = domain` and `-U DOMAIN/user`  or we have to replace word `domain` with `mydomainname` ?

Answer (score 9):

Same issue. I had to add users to the Samba password file with

> sudo smbpasswd -a

Apparently this is because the default configuration in /etc/samba/smb.conf is

> security = user
>
> passdb backend = tdbsam

I’m not using domain controllers or active directory, so I would have thought that access to the regular password file would be the default, but I guess not. It would be nice if that were clear in the documentation I found. The “smbpasswd” reference provided a hint that led to this solution.

Comment: I'm on a domain, and this is the way i think i will have to do this because i don't use my domain user on Linux, its a personal development Linux guest on a windows host.  

Further, I am now able to successfully connect to `smbclient -L localhost` on the guest, but not yet able to connect using the windows host.  I think this was at least one step forward.  I think its ports from here you should include the port numbers to check for in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem with smbclient, and I noticed that it went away when I manually selected the "Just Enable File Sharing" option on the File Sharing dialog you get after manually right-clicking on the folder you want to share.

In some Windows machines (like Windows XP) you need to add this to permit remote sharing for non guest users:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\forceguest=dword:0
```

or, automating using the windows xp command line:

```
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa" /v forceguest /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000 /f
```

After that, smbclient worked without any problems with any user.

Many thanks to jethomas in http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f10/enable-file-sharing-via-the-command-line-133562.html

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 10 (host) and CentOS 7 (guest) I was able to fix the authentication problem by turning off password protected sharing:
Network and sharing center / Advanced sharing settings / all networks / Password protected sharing

This can be helpful for **troubleshooting only**, I would not recommend keeping it off for everyday use.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem when I ran

```
smbclient \\\\[ip]\\[sharedresource]
```

That command asks me to enter password for a root user, however when I entered the password, I received the NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE error.

I added -U to specify my remote machine's username and it worked

```
smbclient \\\\[ip]\\[sharedresource] -U [username]
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to following reason:

1. If valid users is provided in smb.conf cross check the smbpasswd
2. Check the hosts file.

Comment: Not sure why this got down-voted.  This answer pointed me to `smbpasswd` which is what I needed to use to set credentials when I was getting this same error.