# Smbclient fails if called from a java program

Tags: java, printing

Initially I posted this question in this another thread:

[smbclient getting NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE connecting to Windows box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109507/smbclient-getting-nt-status-logon-failure-connecting-to-windows-box/1186154#1186154)

So here it is:

I need to send ZPLII files to a zebra printer from a java procedure inside a oracle database.

If I run a bash command for printing, it works:

```
[oracle@serverws01 ~]$ smbclient //serverps02/zebra_teste -U 'XXXXXX\uuu.uuuuuu%pppppppppp' -W XXXXXX -c 'print /home/oracle/oradata/zpl/et.txt'
Domain=[XXXXXX] OS=[Windows Server 2012 Datacenter 9200]
Server=[Windows Server 2012 Datacenter 6.2]
putting file /home/oracle/oradata/zpl/et.txt as et.txt-18047 (102.4 kb/s) (average 102.4 kb/s)
[oracle@serverws01 ~]$
```

Of course I hided users and passwords of the command. But they are correct.

However, if I need to use this command inside a java source at a oracle database, the same call fails:

```
SQL> declare
2 cmd varchar2(2000);
3 begin
4 cmd := 'smbclient -U ''xxxxxx\xxxxxx%xxxxxx'' //serverps02/zebra_teste -c ''print /home/oracle/oradata/zpl/et.txt'' ';
5 dbms_output.put_line(cmd);
6 rc(cmd);
7 end;
8 /
smbclient -U 'xxxxxx\xxxxxx%xxxxxx' //serverps02/zebra_teste -c 'print /home/oracle/oradata/zpl/et.txt'
**session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE**
X = 1
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

You may find some thing strange at the double quotes this time, diverging from the first example. But is the way that plsql assemblies a string containing a quote.

Does anyone know if some additional permission is required to call `smbclient` inside a Java program?

The printer is a network printer which the print server is a Windows NT.

Comment: Under what UID does this Java program run? If you can find the UID, then you can get a shell as that UID and run the command for testing. If it is `javauser`, then `sudo --user javauser --login`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Simos. I'll find this and post if it worked.